# MySQL-inner join is so slow even with indexing

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, inner-join

there are two tables in my databse: tabel1, table2:

```
table1: {id, name, code, timestamp}
table2: {id, tag1, tag2, tag3}
```

an index has been created on all columns in both tables. now I want to run the following query:

```
SELECT a.* FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.id=b.id
WHERE b.tag1=true
ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC, a.id DESC
LIMIT 24
```

but it is slow (almost 5 seconds, both tables have 1M rows). when I remove `WHERE b.tag1=true` from the query it runs in .1 sec. what is making this query so slow and how to fix it?

indexes:

```
table1: {id: index, name: index, code: index, timestamp: index, (id, timestamp): index}
table2: {id:primary, tag1: index, tag2: index, tag3: index}
```

Comment: Please show the indexes that have been created.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my post.

Comment: Table2 appears poorly designed. I'd start with that.

Comment: @Strawberry why you think it has a bad design?

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2), you can be reasonably confident that your schema design is suboptimal.

Comment: interesting point. thanks. but definitely it cannot be the source of slow query in my case, can it?!

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Comment: @Yatin. the answer is the selected answer. I have only mentioned some more details about the queries.

Comment: @Soheil still, it doesn't belong in the question. You can add the details about the queries into a different answer... Or you can add them into Rick's answer by their permission.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to spell out the indexes is via `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Unfortunately, the `JOIN` prevents efficient use of `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`.

```
b: INDEX(tag1, id)
a: INDEX(timestamp, id)
```

This formulation *might* be better:

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM  table1 a
    INNER JOIN  table2 AS b  ON a.id=b.id
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE id = a.id AND tag1 = true )
    ORDER BY  a.timestamp DESC, a.id DESC
    LIMIT  24
```

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for your version and mine.

Is `tag1` usually true?  That is, will most rows of `a` be filtered out or kept?

If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for both tables, why have 2 separate tables?

Comment: unfortunately your query even took longer to execute.